# Can't use CKEDITOR in django template

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I am using a form without a model class.

```
class ClubWallForm(forms.Form):

    title = forms.CharField(label='Post title', max_length=100)
    description = RichTextField()
    imgURL = forms.CharField(label='Post image url', max_length=100)
    filefield = forms.FileField( label='Select a file',validators=[validate_file_extension] )
```

In my template I used

```
`        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}`
```

CKEDITOR is not geting displayed in my template. 
This is what I am getting.

Inside my views it tried to use ipdb and found that the form has only fields `title imgurl` and `filefield` .

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I got an answer from my friend.
it was to replace

```
description = RichTextField()
```

with

```
description = forms.CharField(label='Description',
                   widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'ckeditor'}))
```

inside `forms.py`
and it is working [image]

Comment: I wouldn't do it like that. You're doing half the work that's done by the form field provided by django-ckeditor, in a way that ties the class name to the field. If ckeditor decides to change the class name, you can fix it again. Plus you don't get the ability to change configs.

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues:

1. `RichTextField` is a *model* field. `RichTextFormField` is the corresponding *form* field.
2. You're not handling the form media in the template. This is outlined [in the documentation](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor#outside-of-django-admin).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **widget tweaks**

First install it by

```
pip install django-widget-tweaks
```

then load it in your ***template*** file with

```
{% load wiget_tweaks %}
```

also use [this](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/) in your site header

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.16.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

now you can set your class to your form with out change it in `forms.py`
so the themplate file should be like this

```
{{ form.description|add_class:"ckeditor" }}
```

**Second way is**:
just use this code in themplate file

```
{{ form.media }}
{{ form.description }}
```